# Spring boot getConversionService returns null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have got a problem using spring boot, in my Controller my param type is Date, URL like this `/testDateParam?date=2018-05-14`  so I write a `String` to `Type` converter, but I still got an error caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date': no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

after debugging , I found method `convertIfNecessary` in class `TypeConverterDelegate` got null:

```
ConversionService conversionService = this.propertyEditorRegistry.getConversionService();
```

I received a `null`, but if I use

```
SpringContextHolder.getBean("conversionService")
```

I can get a valid conversionService I defined:

```
@Bean(name="conversionService")
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean getConversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();

    converters.add(new RyderStringToDateConverter());
    bean.setConverters(converters);
    return bean;
}
```

In a demo project I created, this works fine, but in my working project, I really don't know how to solve it, any idea I will appreciate, thanks

ps: spring boot is the latest version 2.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: can you please format your question so it would be readable

Comment: sorry for that and thanks for editing it for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Springboot you don't have to override parameters conversion.
Just try to add this to your controller:

> @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date date

More about [@DateTimeFormat](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html)

Comment: @RequestMapping("/testDateParam")
@ResponseBody
public String testDateParam(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date date){
        return date.toString();
    }  still got same error ....

Comment: Do you have default jackson deserialization/serialization or do you use custom one for that project?

Comment: found the problem,I use shiro to control my authority ,but somehow there is something wrong when dispatching the request ,and hard to debug